# How to pass same number into many functions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script which generates random number, I also have many other scripts which have to receive that random number from first script.

That is what I tried, but it doesn't work. Always gives 0 as result.

```
    int xNum;

int generateNum()
{
    return Random.Range(10, 100);
}

void Start()
{
    xNum = generateNum();
}


public int Getnumber()
{
    return xNum;
}
```

And then I call Getnumber() method in another script, but as I said it returns always 0. Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong?

P.S random number have to be the same in all other scripts

Comment: Maybe you are creating multiple instances of this class and you call `GetNumber` on an instance where `Start` wasn't called yet.

Comment: Try using Awake instead of Start

Comment: @TimSchmelter No, All my instances has Start functions

Comment: @viva: surely you only want a single instance of the class & call Start once & then Getnumber wherever you need it. Seeing more of your code would help us explain why it is not working as you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to generate this random number only once or "on demand" then I would suggest you doing something like this:

```
int? _generatedRandom;
public int GeneratedRandom
{
    get { 
        if ( !_generatedRandom.HasValue )
            GenerateRandom();

        return _generatedRandom.Value;
    }
}

void GenerateRandom()
{
    _generatedRandom = Random.Next(10, 100);
}
```

Then from your other scripts you can just call :

```
int randomNumber = MeRandomNumberClass.GeneratedRandom;
```

Comment: @m.rogalski Yes I want one generated number, and then share it threw all other scirpts.
 But why my scripts doesn't work?

Comment: @viva I can only assume that your script doesn't work because you're generating random number at start of your whole application. It might be that Unity's `Random`  class uses some weird algorithm to "calculate" new random number using game time which is then seeding the return value with `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code for generating a single number and then passing it outside is perfectly fine.

The error must be in how/from where you call `GetNumber()`, or if your class isn't inheriting from `MonoBehaviour` (this means that `Start` is never executed, so `xNum` stays at its default 0 value).

Please provide all the code of your class, including class declaration, and the code of a script which calls `GetNumber()`.

Comment: 1. All my classes inherit from monobehavior

Answer (score 0):

As some people asked for whole code, I gonna provide code from another script

```
    public Number player;

int num;

private void Start()
{
    num = player.GetComponent<Number>().Getnumber();

    Debug.Log("Number is: " + num);
}
```

Comment: There's your answer. You call GetNumber method before Start was called on that object. Try putting your generator on to the Awake method on Number script.

Comment: @m.rogalski OMG you genius, it helped. Thank you sooooo much.

Comment: One more thing, xNum has to be static, because in other way it still gives 0